# How to search for term "AI" with regex

Tags: javascript, regex, whitespace, metacharacters

I am trying to figure out how to write a regex expression that returns the word "AI" without returning words that contain "ai".

My guess is that I would need to use operators that return "ai" only if there is whitespace one character to the left of "ai" and whitespace one character to the right of "ai".

but allows for punctuation on either end.

The goal is to return a search result like:

```
"AI, the future of computing"

or

"Has AI finally arrived?"

as opposed to

"He said what?" (Notice ai is within the word "said".)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `\b` that denotes a word boundary.
E.g. `\bAI\b`.

Comment: \b(AI)\b should also work I guess... Dont know why this wouldnt work though.

Comment: Cool, any idea how to make it allow for punctuation on either end?

Comment: Would this match strings of text that contain "AI"?

Comment: Or would it just return strings that were equal only to "AI"?

Comment: Example:

"AI"

vs.

"Is AI the future of the world?"

I would like to return any lines that contain the words "AI" not just return the word "AI".

Comment: @user2940471: `\bAI\b` is a pattern that will match and return just "AI". You should read the lines in and check them against this regex pattern.

Comment: `var results = str.match(/.*\bAI\b.*/g)`

Comment: Something like `var re = /\bAI\b/;
var lines = text.split('\n');
for(var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++)
{
  if (str.match(re) != null) 
     ...
}` Whenever you find your match, do whatever you please with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `\b(AI)\b` for this instance.